# Setting up an NLB cluster in Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, nlb

I am setting up a test environment in Hyper-V.

All machines run windows 2008. And configured with a single network card.

I have AD and SQL Server.

I also have 3 web servers that I want to configure in an NLB cluster.

Question is do I need to setup each web server with two network cards? Any thing else I need to watch out for?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up NLB with one network adapter installed. Guest configuration for Hyper-V NLB isn't that different from VMware NLB as far as I know, if you happen across any resources that are specific to VMware.

In our environment, we configure a single network adapter on each member, with multicast mode and a static ARP entry on the router.